# C4430 Error - missing type specifier - int assumed

Tags: c++

I am making a math library (Actually copying one and modifying it.), But after all errors there is just one error I can't seem to get rid of. The Type specifier not found.
It is in line 201 of my Math.h which is this line:

```
     int   Classify(const Polygon &vcPoly);
```

I really tried searching google, but I didn't found anything. For me it's not quite that obvious whats wrong.
Here is the source of the Plane class. In the Math header are also vector, ray, matrix, and some more math classes. The class Polygon comes after the Plane class but I included the definition at the top of the header.

```
    class Plane {
  public:
  Vector m_vcN,       // plane normal vector
            m_vcPoint;   // point on plane
  float     m_fD;        // distance to origin

  //---------------------------------------

  Plane(void) { /* nothing to do */ ; }

  inline void  Set(const Vector &vcN, const Vector &vcP);
  inline void  Set(const Vector &vcN, const Vector &vcP, float fD);
  inline void  Set(const Vector &v0,  const Vector &v1, const Vector &v2);
  inline float Distance(const Vector &vcPoint);
         int   Classify(const Polygon &vcPoly);
  inline int   Classify(const Vector &vcPoint);

  bool Clip(const Ray*, float, Ray*, Ray*);

  bool Intersects(const Vector &vc0, const Vector &vc1, 
                  const Vector &vc2);
  bool Intersects(const Plane &plane, Ray *pIntersection);
  bool Intersects(const Aabb &aabb);
  bool Intersects(const Obb &obb);

 }; // class
```

Hope you could help me.

Comment: You should copy the exact error message, if you want us to give a specific advice.

Comment: Try deleting lines to get down to the minimum number of lines required to reproduce the problem, then you'll either recognize the error or you can post a simplified version here that has all of the features required to recreate.

Comment: May it be, that Plane and Polygon are mutually dependent on one another, and that the Polygon header includes your Plane header? In that case one of the headers will normally not be included the second time round and the type will be undefined. Try putting a forward declaration of Polygon before Plane definition instead of including the header.

Comment: They are indeed dependend on each other, so that's why I included the class Polygon; at the top of the header as definition. And I don't include any other headers then <cmath> Everything is in one header: the math.h,-----I ment that I included/typed the like class Polygon; Not included a file or something

Comment: @Christain, you need to post the entire Math.h file. Should be very easy to sort out when you do that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the type `Polygon` is not know in that line. Did you include the right header files? My guess is that `Polygon.h` (or something like that) is missing.

**EDIT:** if all classes are included in the same header, maybe you have to make sure that the class is defined (with a prototype) before it is needed as a type. That means you can place class prototypes in the *beginning* of your header file:

```
// prototype for Polygon
class Polygon;
```

Comment: @Christian - typo or missing semicolon for Polygon declaration?

Comment: The polygon class is also in the Math header, just like the plane class. The Polygon class only comes AFTER the plane class. That's why I added the like: class Polygon; at the top of the header, as definition. But I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int and after that comes the error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&' error, which is of course related

Comment: I did do that. ( Thanks a LOT for the advice by the way! ) I typed that line, but it doens't seem to help. The error message is still there. The strange part is that there is no: Type definition not known error or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of two header including each other:

Plane.h:
    #include "Polygon.h"

Polygon.h
    #include "Plane.h"

Since `#include` means 'preprocess the named file and insert contents here' this would lead to infinite recursion, which is why a common technique is to use 'include guards' in header file, in the form of:

```
#ifndef _SOMETHING_H_
#define _SOMETHING_H_
// header contents here
#endif
```

How this works, is if you include Polygon.h first, it defines the preprocessor symbol, and then goes on to include the files which you `#include` at the top of your header. One of these is Plane.h, which then in turn tries to include Polygon.h, but because Polygon's guard symbol is defined, it gets included as an empty file.

This prevents infinite recursion, but because of this  there is no definition of Polygon type preceding the included Plane definition.

The solution is in at least one of these headers (and possibly in both) to replace the inclusion of header with a forward definition of the type. So in Plane.h instead of:

```
#include "Polygon.h"
```

you do:

```
class Polygon;
```

And you may do the same in Polygon.h.

Note that a forward declared type without a definition is what's called an incomplete type, and there are restrictions of how you can use it in the header: you may define pointers or references to it (which is how it's used in the example, but you may not define instances, pass by value, access fields etc.

Comment: I found the answer!

It turned out that I had to inline the function in the CPP file and inline the function in the class, then everything worked out!

I guess it wasn't overloaded because one was an inlined function and one was not.

Thanks a lot everyone.